# Groups and Binary Operations over functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Please advice me on my answers/understanding.

Decide which of the following pairs (G,∗) are groups; for those which are, say what the identity and inverses are, and for the ones which aren't, say which axiom fails.

a. $G$ the set $C([0; 1])$ of continuous functions $f : [0, 1] \to \Bbb{R}$, with $f * g
$defined by $(f * g)(x) = f(x) + g(x).$

Is the identity the zero function i.e.$$f:[0,1]\to 0$$while the inverse is $-f(x)$

b. G the set $C([0; 1])$ with $*$ defined by $(f * g)(x) = f(x)g(x).$

The identity the "one" function i.e.$$f:[0,1]\to 1$$while the inverse is $f^{-1}(x)$ doesn't aways exist i.e. when f is not bijective. E.g. $f(x)=(x-0.5)^2 $on$ [0,1]$ fails horizontal line test i.e. $f(.4)=f(.6)  $ but $ 0.4≠0.6$ . Therefore, G isn't a group.

Comment: Can you exhibit, in particular, a function without an inverse for part (b)?

Comment: Is f(x)=(x-0.5)^2 on [0,1] a suitable example as it fails horizontal line test i.e. f(.4)=f(.6) but .4$\neq$.6

Comment: I think you got (b) wrong. In the group, $f^{-1}$ isn't supposed to be inversion with respect to function composition (unless the group operation is function composition, which it is not.) The inverse is $\frac{1}{f(x)}$; does it always exist as a continuous function?

Comment: Hint: what if $f(x) = 0$ for some value $x$?

Comment: @ Respawned Fluff. Thanks. I get it now. G isn't a group because the inverse $\frac{1}{f(x)}$does not exist when $f(x)=0 $ on $ [0,1]$